# how to set form value with external select value

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework

so i am using the play framework and I'm try to create multiple submit buttons that call the one form:

So what I have is a list of strings, and i would like to create two buttons that will go back to the server and complete an event, the first is send the second is cancel. What i would like to also do is set the source value equal to what is selected in the foo select object. How would I go about doing this? Do i need to create a javascript even that is fired from the form and then get the var inside that function and then fire off the submit? Im not 100% familiar with play framework and scala, so im not sure if i can get it somehow inside this code without using a new method.

```
@(myList: List[String], theForm: Form[Obj])
@import helper._
@main("myVar Controller") {

<select id="foo">
</select>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
    @for(myVar <- myList) {
        <td>@myVar
        @form(routes.Application.method()) {
        <div id="hiddenForm" style="visibility:hidden">
            <input type="text" name="commandID" id="commandID" value="10" />    //Send Code
            <input type="text" name="source" id="source" value=**"Put selected value of foo here" />**
            <input type="text" name="destination" id="destination" value="@myVar" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
        }
        @form(routes.Application.method()) {
        <div id="hiddenForm" style="visibility:hidden">
            <input type="text" name="commandID" id="commandID" value="18" />    //Undo code
            <input type="text" name="source" id="source" value=**"Put selected value of foo here" />**
            <input type="text" name="destination" id="destination" value="@myVar" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Undo" />
        }
        </td>
    }
    </tr>
</table>
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the html isn't valid.
You should first make sure that there aren't elements that have the same id.

You have to use javascript to change a value in your form.
I'm not familiar with scalar or playframework, but if they allow you to use jQuery, I recommend the following solution.

```
$("#foo").bind("change", function(){$("#source").val($("#foo").val()));});​
```

**example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/RubenJonker/a8a8p/5

If they don't allow you to use jQuery, then you should put some javascript in the onchange event of the select.

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById('source').value = this.value">
</select>
```

**example:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/RubenJonker/a8a8p/4

Comment: Thanks that works well. And the play framework does have access to jquery.
But unfortunately the example jquery example you linked didnt work when i ran it.

The second example worked fine though.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else has this problem I used the following to solve my problem: Thanks Ruup as your code was the reason why I solved the problem

html:

```
<select id="foo" >
    <option></option>
    <option value="test">test</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="" name="field" id="field" />​
```

and javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
obj = document.getElementById("foo");
obj.onchange = function()
{
     var elements = document.getElementsByName('field');
     for (i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
     {
         elements[i].value = $('#foo').val();
                 }
 }; });
```